# Opening data file in app from email

Tags: ios, xml, import

I have updated my `info.plist` file of my app to reflect a new file type (called `.ftl`).

When I attach a file of this type to an email, iOS recognises the file type as one that can be handed off to my app (my app's icon appears when the file is touched in the email). However, when I select the icon, my App does not launch.

In my App delegate I'm using the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:` delegate method to handle the processing of the associated `NSURL`. When I `NSLog` this method, it is clear that the method is not called.

Any ideas? I've had this working in iOS 4. I then upgraded Xcode to test against an iPad running iOS 6 and have come across this dead end. The rest of my app works fine.

Further to Rob's request, here are my CFBundleDocumentTypes and UTExportedTypeDeclarations from my info.plist file. Thanks:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.yourcompany.blinkapp.ftl</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Blink FTL Sheet</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Blink FTL Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.blinkapp.ftl</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>ftl</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I also tried using public.data instead of public.text in my UTTypeConformsTo. Same problem.

Comment: Perhaps those people voting to close this because it is "unclear what you're asking" can comment, because it strikes me that the question is perfectly clear, even if the source of the problem isn't. If you have suggestions on how to make this question more clear, share that.

Answer (score 1):

After several days of tearing my hair out over this issue, and some fantastic input from some of the members of this site, I found to source of the bug:

On inspecting my organiser device console (window > organiser, then console of device you are testing on), I noticed the following warning:

```
LaunchServices: Invalid LSOpenOperation request - No applications found to open document
```

I looked this up on the Apple developer forum and came across:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4489540?start=0&tstart=0

This looks like an issue first seen in iOS 6, requiring strict consistency between the mime type of the data enclosed within the file you are attempting to open in your app, and the declared in you plist.info file. Basically in iOS 4, my app opened a file containing .xml content enclosed in a file of type .ftl with the following info.plist entry:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.blinkapp.ftl</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>ftl</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/blinkapp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

However, in iOS 6, it is essential to declare the UTTypeConformsTo as XML:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.yourcompany.blinkapp.ftl</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>ftl</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/blinkapp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

... note public.xml NOT public.data

It might sound obvious, but as I say, under iOS 4 and 5, my app ran without a hitch ... and suddenly in iOS6, failed to even launch. Good luck and hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution for your issue!

Comment: I know it may feel weird, but you should feel free "accept" your own answer so this question is flagged as closed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CFBundleDocumentTypes` (the "Document types"), you don't have a `CFBundleTypeRole` (the "Role"). According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW6), "This key specifies the app’s role with respect to the type. The value can be Editor, Viewer, Shell, or None. This key is required." I might try setting that and see if that fixes the issue.

While I'm at it, I'd also be inclined to define a mime type, e.g. a `public.mime-type` of `application/flight` (or whatever your app name is).

---

Looking at your code, the signature for the [`openURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a) was not complete. The method signature is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // handle the URL here
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Unfortunately neither of these ideas - although both valid - fixes the problem. Am I right in saying that if my icon appears when the email attachment is touched, that the App should at least be launched? Assuming the info.plist file is in order? Is that your understanding?

Comment: @LeeBarringer Yes, that's my understanding. Sorry it didn't work out.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This problem is a major headache - as the app worked beautifully on IOS 4. Regards, Lee

Comment: @LeeBarringer This works in iOS 6, too, so I don't know what's going on in your situation. If you use `public.data`, you should see list of apps, yours should be there, and when you tap on it, your `openURL` method in your app delegate should be called.

Comment: Thanks again. This issue still open if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: @LeeBarringer I'd suggest (a) start with `public.data` instead of `public.text`, because the latter may trigger preview rather than a traditional "open in" dialog; (b) creating a new test application with otherwise similar `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` and `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and make sure the problem isn't a result of your particular project (i.e. I've encountered curious bugs where Xcode was failing to update the app correctly, only solved via removing derived data and/or completely uninstalling app and reinstalling).

Comment: If all else fails, upload a simplified rendition of your project soemwhere and we can take a look at it. But the above `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` and `CFBundleDocumentTypes` (with my three changes, `public.data`, adding "role" and adding "mime type") seem to work fine on iOS 6.1 fine.

Comment: (btw, when I say "completely uninstalling app and reinstalling", I'm obviously talking about the iOS app you're developing, not Xcode.)

Comment: Thanks Rob. Away doing the day job for a while - looking into your suggestions now.

Comment: Hi Rob, Could it be something to do with cfbundleurltypes? I've seen a few posts connected with an App not launching in connection with this info.plist setting?

Comment: @LeeBarringer No, that's used if you're implementing a custom URL scheme. Completely separate issue. You can use a custom URL scheme, too, if you want, but it is separate from the file types associated with an app. I'd suggest fixing the file association problem before pursuing custom URL scheme (if it make sense to do custom URL scheme for your app at all; that's unlikely).

Comment: Rob, I'm a bit concerned about deleting the project and reinstalling. Everything else works well on it and I'm so novice at all this it would be a disaster to accidentally introduce any more issues. I've edited then info file as suggested. No joy. Could I send you a copy of my project by email? My company are so desperate to get this bug fixed they're even willing to offer a small bounty to fix it!!

Comment: @LeeBarringer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33063/discussion-between-rob-and-lee-barringer)